# Android Studio project doesn't recognize some classes since got my Mac

Tags: java, macos, android-studio, oop, importerror

Since I got my Mac, I've encountered some problems when pulling my projects from Github.
The app still works even though Android Studio does not recognize some classes.
However, it is very annoying that I have to remove the import lines and write them again every time I pull my project from Github.
Could the problem be that I use a Mac while my colleagues who work on the same project use Windows?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My problem was solved after I cleared the system cache.
If you have the same problem, just follow these steps:

1. From the main menu, select File.
2. Click invalidate Caches/Restart.
3. Click Invalidate and Restart.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try rebuilding the project (Build -> Rebuild Project). Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I tried to rebuild, and I got the following message:
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 317ms

Comment: I fixed the Gradle 8.0 issue, but the main problem still exists.